# How do I connect my USB-C iPad/iPhone to a headset and Mac at the same time?

Tags: ipad, audio, usb

I own an iPad Air 5, which, like recent Apple devices, lacks a headphone jack. In the past, I successfully used a Belkin adapter with a lightning connector that allowed for simultaneous data, charging, and audio connectivity. The specific product was the Belkin 3.5 mm Audio + Charge RockStar (https://www.belkin.com/3.5-mm-audio-charge-rockstar/P-F8J212.html).

However, with the transition to USB-C, I purchased the Belkin 3.5mm Audio + USB-C Charge Adapter (https://www.belkin.com/3.5mm-audio-usb-c-charge-adapter/P-NPA004.html), hoping it would offer the same functionality. Unfortunately, it does not support data connectivity. Is there an alternative solution or adapter that allows for connecting my iPad Air 5 to both a guitar and my Mac simultaneously, considering the limitations of the USB-C model?

Comment: USB bus goes only one way - what will the Mac and iPad and Guitar do to collaborate? Are you just trying to route analog audio from the guitar to the iPad? If you describe a bit more of the setup and what your goal is you might get a much faster answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to connect my Guitar to the iPad (with iRig 2). For the sake of simplicity, it could be just headset connected to iPad. At the same time, I want to to sync and charge my iPad with my Mac.

Comment: Aah. You can probably get everything needed except the sync (which I think you know) let's see what other people can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible, because in USB connection one end has to act as host (the side that controls the connection) and other as device. For the headset adapter, the iPad needs to be the host but for computer connection the computer is host and the iPad is the device.

If it is possible to use WiFi or Ethernet for the data connection, that should allow the iPad to be the host. I had a similar problem when I was developing for iOS and iRig HD, and the solution was connecting Xcode debugger over WiFi.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. I did not know that USB-C lacks some features, that good old Lightning has.

Comment: I suspect a working solution is possible but would cost more than most people are willing to pay, which may be a distinction without a difference.  Cost will be a consideration in any solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative solution or adapter that allows for connecting
> my iPad Air 5 to both a guitar and my Mac simultaneously, considering
> the limitations of the USB-C model?

Have you tried the USB-C to Lightning adapter and the old Lightning to audio + sync adapter?  I have my doubts it would work but it is possible.

What follows has a bit of speculation based on what I learned in doing some circuit design and reading of the USB spec.  Since Apple isn't exactly open on how Lightning works there's a lot of speculation about on how Lightning works on the internet so I may as well pile on.

To take an educated guess why the Lightning adapter allows for data, power, and audio when the USB-C adapter does not requires a bit of looking at what is known about Lightning.  We can start with the pin identifiers shown on the Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)

On the Lightning connector is power, ground, then three data paths.  There's "lane 0", "lane 1", and a lane for ID and configuration.  I would speculate that with the audio + sync adapter the Lightning connector puts one lane into USB host mode for a common USB audio I/O chip, and the other lane into USB device mode for syncing to a computer or to communicate power with an "old school" USB-BC charger.  The ID/config lane just then tells the iProduct the adapter is plugged in and what kind of signals to expect on the data lanes, and that it can pass through power.

USB-C is like Lightning in many ways, such as having a configuration data lane for identifying the kind of adapter and multiple data lanes that can be switched into different modes.  The different modes that USB-C can go into can be seen on the USB-C Wikipedia page.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#USB-C_receptacle_pin_usage_in_different_modes

The most obvious mode for an adapter meant to provide power in and audio out is the "audio accessory mode".  This would be supported by Apple iProducts as well as most any USB-C device designed and built after that mode was added to the USB-C spec in 2016 or so.  In this mode the USB-C lanes normally used for USB 2.0 data are used for audio, the power path is put in a low power 5 volt mode, and the other "super speed" pins are ignored.  I would expect Belkin to use the audio accessory mode for maximum compatibility among different products, not just those from Apple.

At this point I will wade deeper into speculation.

Apple is going to want to keep consumers of their iProducts happy so they produced an adapter for connecting old Lightning cables and adapters to their new USB-C iProducts.  Looking at the adapter product description on the Apple website it states it will support audio, charging, and data.  https://www.apple.com/us_smb_83039/shop/product/MUQX3AM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-adapter

How does this adapter help?  I speculate that this adapter puts USB-C ports on Apple iProducts into a kind of "Lightning mode".  How does that work?  The USB-C spec has a "debug accessory mode" which is really more of an "anything goes mode".  It would be relatively trivial to have this Lightning adapter trigger a mode in Apple USB-C port to support Lightning signals.  I can think of a half dozen ways to make this work, and since Apple controls what goes in their iProducts and adapters it would be trivial to pick something that would work and add support for this adapter with a software update.

I went through that long explanation for two reasons.  First, I'm a huge computer geek and I love to discuss how computers work.  Second, I want the reader to have some background on how Lightning and USB-C work so that they can better understand what to expect of their Lightning and USB-C devices.  With that understanding comes why I suspect a Lightning to USB-C adapter and the Lighting audio + charge adapter would allow for data but the USB-C audio + charge adapter would not.

If anyone tries this then please let me know how it goes.  I'm thinking of buying the USB-C to Lightning adapter to play with in spite of not having any real need for it.  No need yet anyway, that can change.  If it works like I suspect then that's just one more reason to get it.

Comment: Sadly, [USB-C to Lightning Adapter] -> [Belkin Rockstar] does not solve the problem. The syncing is unavailable.

Comment: @RomanZakharov  Thanks for the follow-up.  I guess it was too much to ask for the Lightning adapter to add functionality beyond what USB-C offers.  I suspect it would be rather trivial to implement a Lightning adapter that had all the functionality of a "native" Lightning port but to do so would drive up costs considerably for little added benefit to most users.  It is perhaps a big ask to have any kind of Lightning adapter.  I'm considering if I should add to my answer above given the new information or just let it stand as a lesson for others.  Thanks again.